# JMeter: How is it possible to load test live streaming videos which wont be available during load testing

Tags: jmeter, broadcast, live, blazemeter

First I would like to know that lets say, there is live football match on 20th oct, 2018 and we have to load test live streaming of same match. Obviosuly, live will be available on date mentioned but how would I test for the live video streaming which wont be available before mentioned date?

Comment: Any feedback on answers ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to others. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You will need to set up streaming of another match or any other video content of similar length/resolutions to check whether your environment is ready to server the stream to anticipated number of consumers without any hardware/software/networking issues.

For example previous match streaming results can be used for test purposes, I would recommend approaching it as follows:

1. Set up monitoring of all your infrastructure (availability of servers/services, resource availability, CPU, RAM, etc. usage). If you don't have an [APM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_performance_management) tool in place you can consider using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) for this
2. Create a JMeter Test Plan which will represent a real user consuming the stream. Depending on format(s) of stream delivery you will need to either go for [JMeter HLS Plugin](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/tree/master/hls#hls-plugin) or implement your test using one of the approaches described in the [Load Testing Video Streaming with JMeter: Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-video-streaming-with-jmeter-learn-how) article
3. Parameterise your test to represent variety of users requesting streams of different resolution/bandwidth, probably even using [different network types](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/Controlling%20Bandwidth%20in%20JMeter%20to%20simulate%20different%20networks)
4. Run your test, analyse results using JMeter's [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html), raise issues if any, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You would usually setup a similar test stream available on which to build your test plan.

Note that if you don't want to script anything, you could use this commercial plugin for JMeter which allows testing Live and VOD for HLS, MPEG-DASH, HSS and HDS on premise or from the cloud, see:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/setup-video-streaming-load-test-with-ubikloadpack-jmeter-and-aws/
- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/running-video-streaming-load-test-with-taurus-jmeter-and-ubikloadpack/

Disclaimer : We are providers of this solution